# SharePoint online PowerApp Canvas Form 1 button is disable waits for approval before button enables to click the button to go to next Form 2

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, powerapps-canvas

I have a question for SharePoint online how do I keep the Disable Button in PowerApps until the Form responses are approved by the Manager/Supervisor. The Form edit is created in Canvas. Can anyone recommend what step-by-step I need to make the functions work?

For example, in SharePoint online PowerApp I have a First_list Form and Second_list Form. The End-user fills out First_list Form and Submit but the End-users waits until it received the Approval email notification then the Button should be able to appear enabled to navigate to Second_list Form.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a third list with only form id from the first list. While the id of the form is still on that last, the button is blocked.